# Vim: <leader> key sequences are interfused with normal mode mappings

Tags: vim

I'm trying to define mappings for "cpp" filetype:

```
autocmd! FileType cpp map <leader>c echo "test c"

autocmd! FileType cpp map <leader>r echo "test r"

autocmd! FileType cpp map <leader>t echo "test t"
```

My leader key is redefined:

```
let mapleader = ","
```

When I open *.cpp file only one of the mappings works as expected: the ",t" sequence makes the "echo" happen, but the other two behaves as if there were no any mappings defined: ",r" makes Vim to switch to replace mode and ",c" brings Vim to insert mode.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how your example (including `,c` one) could work: you forgot to prepend echo with a colon. But there is another mistake: according to the help:

> :au[tocmd]! [group] {event} {pat} [nested] {cmd}
>
> Remove all autocommands associated with {event} and {pat}, and add the command {cmd}.

So, the last one (`,t`) should replace all previous ones.

There are also another things you should to consider:

1. Don't use `map`, use `noremap` instead: it may once save you from doing a debug job after you add some mapping.
2. If you define filetype mapping you should normally add `<buffer>` as an argument to `:noremap` in a position before `{lhs}`: it will make this mapping local to the current buffer.
3. In case you want to re-source vimrc you should put all command into augroup:

   ```
   augroup VimrcCpp
       autocmd!
       autocmd FileType cpp nnoremap <buffer> <leader>c :echo "c"<CR>
       autocmd FileType cpp nnoremap <buffer> <leader>r :echo "r"<CR>
       autocmd FileType cpp nnoremap <buffer> <leader>t :echo "t"<CR>
   augroup END
   ```
4. I would have removed it from vimrc and added to ~/.vim/ftplugin/cpp.vim (`after` directory is to be used only to override options that you don't like if they are unconditionally defined by a plugin. If there are no mapping conflicts, don't use `after`).

Comment: Thank you very much for brilliant answer ZyX! With your help it works now!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you put those mapping in a file called `cpp.vim` placed in your `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/` (or any equivalent based on OS) directory.

Vim automatically loads it as long as you have

```
filetype plugin on
```

in your `.vimrc`.

This saves you writing autocommands and keeps your configuration well organized.